# Laravel - Update database record if already exists - all fields

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get Laravel to update a database record, if it's already exists. This is my table:

```
id        |    booking_reference | description | date
------------------------------------------------------
PRI KEY   |    UNIQUE            | MEDIUM TEXT | DATE
AUTO INC  |                      |
```

My model looks like this:

`Document.php`:

```
class Document extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'booking_reference', 'description', 'date'
    ];

}
```

And my controller, looks like this - please note that it's `webhook()` that's being called.

`DocumentController.php`:

```
class DocparserController extends Controller
{
    //This is the function to capture the webhook
    public function webhook(Request $request)
    {
        $document = new Document();

        $document->fill($request->all());
        //Grab the date_formatted field from our request.
        $document->date = $request->input('date_formatted');

        $document->updateOrCreate(
            ['booking_reference' => $document->booking_reference],
            //How can I do so it updates all fields?

        );

        return response()->json("OK");
    }
}
```

So my problem is, that I cannot figure out how to update my entire row, where the `booking_reference` is already present.

I want to update all fields (description, date), **without** having to enter them all like:

```
 ['booking_reference' => $document->booking_reference],
 ['description' => $document->comments, 'date' => $document->date]
```

Comment: Why not use `$request->all()` directly or make a method which maps/translates values from the input to a given array (having the appropriate keys: `'booking_reference', 'description', 'date'`) since you are sending `date_formatted` instead of `date`?

Comment: @ka_lin, I have to map specific fields from my request. For example, `$request->formatted_date` is set to `$document->date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Document::updateOrCreate(
    ['booking_reference' => $request->input('booking_reference')],
    $request->all() + ['date' => $request->input('date_formatted')]
);
```

If you wanted to adjust the request inputs before calling that you could do that mapping and slim this down.

```
$request->merge(['date' => $request->input('date_formatted')]);
// now $request->all() has `date`

...updateOrcreate(
    [...],
    $request->all(),
)
```

That particular field has to be mapped at some point ... if you really really wanted to you could actually have a middleware do this mapping, which would slim this down to just `$request->all()` as the second array.

Or even set up a mutator for `date_formatted` that sets `date`.

Basically this has to happen somewhere, it just depends where.

Comment: This is very clean and just what I was looking for! Didn't know about the `merge()` function - definitely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of the following to check if the records exists and run the update query if the data already exists.

```
$user = Document::where('booking_reference', '=', $request->booking_reference)->first();
if ($user === null) {
   // user doesn't exist
}
```

OR

```
if (Document::where('booking_reference', '=', $request->booking_reference)->count() > 0) {
   // user found
}
```

Or even nicer

```
if (Document::where('booking_reference', '=', $request->booking_reference)->exists()) {
   // user found
}
```

And i do not think you can update an entire row of data at once. You have to point which attribute to update to which one.

Comment: "So my problem is, that I cannot figure out how to update my entire row", have you read the question?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a private function to normalize the input data:

```
private static function transformRequestInput($requestArray)
{
    $map = ['date_formatted'=>'date'];
    foreach($map as $key=>$newKey){
        if(isset($requestArray[$key])) {
            $requestArray[$newKey] = $requestArray[$key];
            unset($requestArray[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $requestArray;
}
```

And I would use it like so:

```
    $document->updateOrCreate(
        ['booking_reference' => $document->booking_reference],
        self::transformRequestInput($request->all())
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a class or object to associative array (properties must be public):

```
$updateArr = (array) $document;
$document->updateOrCreate($updateArr);
```

However, you use a protected property ($fillable) so you must:

```
$document = new Document();
$document->fill($request->all());
//Grab the date_formatted field from our request.
$document->date = $request->input('date_formatted');

$reflection = new ReflectionClass($document);
$property = $reflection->getProperty('fillable');
$property->setAccessible(true);
$updateArr = (array) $property->getValue($document);
$property->setAccessible(false);

$document->updateOrCreate($updateArr);
return response()->json("OK");
```